# How to create a boxplot for multiple dependent variables from the WeightLoss dataset?

Tags: r, anova, multivariate-testing, manova

I'm trying to make a boxplot from the `WeightLoss` dataset from the `car` package. The variables of interest are separated by month, so I made boxplots by month separately, with all the groups (Control, Diet, Diet and Exercise) showing. I only want to get the boxplot of the group Diet and their weight loss across the span of 3 months in 1 boxplot instead of 3. To clarify, I need `ylab="Weight loss"` and `xlab="Month"` as my axes. I have no idea on how to do this though.

This is the first feasible set of boxplots I was able to make, but they're separated by month and all the groups show up in the boxplot.

```r
library(car)
library(DescTools)

boxplot(wl1 ~ group, data=WeightLoss, 
        main="Weight Loss after 1 month",
        ylab="Weight loss",
        xlab="Group")
boxplot(wl2 ~ group, data=WeightLoss, 
        main="Weight Loss after 2 months",
        ylab="Weight loss",
        xlab="Group")
boxplot(wl3 ~ group, data=WeightLoss, 
        main="Weight Loss after 3 months",
        ylab="Weight loss",
        xlab="Group")
```

I tried to separate the group I only wanted like this:

```r
boxplot(wl1 ~ group$Diet, data=WeightLoss,  
        main="Weight Loss after 1 month",
        ylab="Weight loss",
        xlab="Group")
```

but I keep on getting this error:

```r
Error in group$diet : $ operator is 
    invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: The diet variable does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could first `subset` to diet group, then `reshape` the months into long format (`cbind`ing an ID column first).

```
library(car)  ## to load `WeightLoss` data

subset(cbind(WeightLoss, id=seq_len(nrow(WeightLoss))), group == 'Diet') |>
  reshape(varying=c("wl1", "wl2", "wl3"), timevar='months', dir='long', sep='') |>
  boxplot(wl ~ months, data=_)
```

[image]

The plot shows the weight loss in the respective month.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm curious, where does the `wl` object get formed? I would like to do another boxplot but using the self-esteem variable (se1, se2, se3). I'm not sure which to change? I changed `wl` to `se` and then again the object was not found. Any hints to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: @strugglingstudent It's the `varying=` argument of `reshape`. Please see edit where I made it more explicit. It's actually better to use names instead of numbers, sorry for my laziness.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```r
boxplot(wl1 ~ as.character(group),
         data= 
   WeightLoss[WeightLoss$group=="Diet", ],
         main="Weight Loss after 1 month",
         ylab="Weight loss",
         xlab="Group")
```

[image: boxplot produced by the code above]

Comment: You can make cleaner code by using the `subset=` argument of `boxplot`